# Webflow, JSF, Primefaces: Why is this List empty?

Tags: jsf, portlet, primefaces, spring-webflow, jsr286

I have four lists in my webflow, which I load from my service layer. 
They look like this one:

```
<evaluate expression="partyService.getPostalAddresses()" result="viewScope.uiPostalAddresses"
            result-type="java.util.ArrayList" />
```

In my JSF/Primefaces UI, I have this:

```
<p:dataTable id="partyAddressTable" widgetVar="partyAddressTable"
        var="address" value="#{viewScope.uiPostalAddresses}" style="width:100%;"
        rows="#{msg.parties_address_table_rows}" styleClass="partyAddressTable"
        paginator="#{msg.parties_address_table_paginator}"
        paginatorPosition="#{msg.parties_address_table_paginatorPosition}"
        paginatorTemplate="#{msg.parties_address_table_paginatorTemplate}"
        lazy="#{msg.parties_address_table_lazy}" selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{viewScope.selectedItem}"
        scrollable="#{msg.parties_address_table_scrollable}">
    [...]
</p:dataTable>
```

When I open my page, webflow loads the list and JSF/Primefaces shows it correctly.
And then, if I press my "addEntry"-Button, the entries in the list all **disappear**. I saw that webflow is adding one entry to the list correctly.

Webflow "addEntry"-Snippet:

```
<transition on="addPostal"> 
    <evaluate expression="uiPostalAddresses.add(personService.getEmptyPostalAddress())" />
</transition>
```

It all happens in the same view-state and the whole application is running in a **Portlet** on Liferay.

I have no more idea what the problem could be. Could you please help me?

I'm using:

- JSF: 1.2
- Primefaces: 1.1
- Webflow: 2.3
- Portlet: 2.0 --> JSR286
- Liferay:
  6.0.6

Comment: Can you post the full code for the <view-state> in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

I worked on a pointer to uiPostalAddresses and if I clear the list on party and addAll to party, the list is empty.

So that was my fault ;-)